Can’t access c$ by ip address but can with computer name
I have an issue with my work in a domain environment. I cannot access the C drive of one computer from another using the IP address, but I can access it using the computer name. I’ve tried many solutions, but nothing resolves the problem. I would appreciate any suggestions. Here’s an example:
\ip\c$ – doesn’t work
\computername\c$ – works

Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see On-Topic. Please talk to your IT department.

most likely, your org is configured to use SMB signing, and the admins have locked out the NTLM family of protocols for authentication (forcing kerberos authentication).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-signing-overview . You won't be able to do anything about it without your IT department's assistance.
